# How to set git diff parameter in Github desktop gui

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

Is there a way in the latest github git gui for mac (desktop.github.com)
to set the git diff parameters? For example I would like the git-gui to ignore-whitespace-change in diff

```
git diff --ignore-space-change
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Apr. 2021, 5 years later, GitHub Desktop can [actually hide whitespace](https://github.blog/2021-04-28-github-desktop-hiding-whitespace-expanding-diffs-repo-aliases/#hide-whitespace-in-diffs) (GitHub Desktop 2.8):

> ### Hide whitespace in diffs

> Similar to being able to see more context around your changes, sometimes there are a lot of whitespace changes in a file that don’t allow you to get a clear picture of the substantive changes that happened.
>
> Now, in both changes and history, you can optionally hide whitespace changes to allow you to focus just on the more meaningful changes to your code.
>
> This feature was built almost entirely by Steven Yeh ([@say25](https://github.com/say25)), a fantastic and close community contributor to GitHub Desktop. Steven is a long-time open source contributor to GitHub Desktop, and we’re immensely grateful for him continuing to help improve the product.
>
> [image: https://github.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/GitHub-Desktop-hiding-whitespace-changes.gif]

Answer (score 2):

`git-gui` is not the same as the [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com). `git-gui` comes with the Git installation (you can download the latest for OSX from [git-scm.com/download/mac](https://git-scm.com/download/mac); the current version is 2.9.2 as of this answer date). Once installed, you can run `git-gui` from the command line (it installs at `/usr/local/opt/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui`). You can then access **Preferences** in **Git Gui** menu, and put `-w` (or `--ignore-all-space`) in **Additional Diff Parameters** field to ignore whitespace change, or add any other [git-diff parameter](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

**GitHub Desktop**, on the other hand, does not have such option available.